# Docusign Post-signing completed landing not shown

Tags: docusignapi

I have set my signer as both captive and embedded signer by setting the embedded_recipient_start_url = SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN. After this, when the signer signs the docusign via email, remote signing, they are prompted to log in to docusign, instead of the usual Post-signing completed landing pages.

Does anyone know how to display the completed page after signing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Read this [excellent article by Drew](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-hybrid-captiveremote-signing-embeddedrecipientstarturl) to see what you can do.
But when you use remote signing, AFAIK, you cannot define the post-signing URL, that is only possible with embedded (captive) signing.

(if you still require this, you may need to build your own server to process URLs that you send yourself to your recipients, this can all be done, but not recommended).